# How to refer to a data member of an object inside nested objects?

Tags: java, android

I have a java class User which has the member variables firstName and lastName shown below :

```
public class User {

public String firstName;
public String lastName;

public void register()
{
    // do something
}

public void registerFacebook(Facebook facebookObj)
{
    mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener(){

        public void onComplete(String response, Object state){
            this.firstName = "John";
            this.lastName = "Doe";
            String userRegistrationResponse = this.register();
        }
```

As you can see in the above code, I am trying to set the firstName and lastName for the current object of the class User. However, since the code is inside the object of the class RequestListener, it is not possible.

How do i refer to the firstName and lastName then ?

I get the error :

```
firstName cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

Answer (score 2):

It works because you're using an *anonymous inner class*, which has an implicit reference to the instance of `User` in which it's constructed. That's what `firstName` and `lastName` refer to in this case.

However, you need to remove the `this` or change it to `User.this`. For example:

```
public class Test {

    private String name;

    Test() {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                name = "Fred"; // Or Test.this.name = "Fred"
            }
        };
        System.out.println(name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

See [section 15.8.4 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4) for more details of how `Test.this` works.

Answer (score 0):

No problem either remove the `this.` part (as `this` refers to the instance it is in, which is the anonymous class). Or specify it fully/correctly:

```
User.this.firstName = ...
```